# LuaSocket requires superuser to create server

Tags: lua, serversocket, luasocket

When I try to create a socket listening on any port using LuaSocket on Ubuntu, the creation of the socket fails with "permission denied":

```
require("socket")

server, msg = socket.bind("*", 23)

if not server then print(msg) end
```

however, when the same script is executed as superuser (using sudo), creation of the server works just fine. Is there any reason why LuaSocket cannot normally create a server? Can I do anything (either in Lua or on the Ubuntu server) such that there is no need for executing the script as superuser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not LuaSocket specific problem, but a deliberate Ubuntu (and many other Linux/UNIX) security restriction. Non-privileged users cannot bind to ports under 1024. You can use [`privbind`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/privbind.1.html) to work around this limitation.